# improper printf in semaphore

Tags: c, semaphore, race-condition

i have a log function which is called just after `sem_post(&sem_ptr)`:

```
sem_post(&sem_ptr);
write(STD_OUT, "blah", 5);
```

when i use these sequence of code, i mean calling `write` after `sem_post`,
sometimes the "blah" string is printed twice, but when i use the following sequence of code:

```
write(STD_OUT, "blah", 5);
sem_post(&sem_ptr);
```

the output is correct and the "blah" string is printed once.
can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: `sem_post` unlocks your semaphore - that is why the second code example works as expected.

Comment: @fpmurphy ok but why it is printed twice? just for this reason?

Comment: To figure that out, you need to supply a minimum reproducible example.